# Proving the principle of explosion in Agda

Tags: agda, theorem-proving, type-theory

Since Agda is intuitionistic one has to postulate the law of excluded middle. But as far as I know, intuitionistic logic accepts *ex falso quodlibet* or the principle of explosion (the theorem that everything follows from absurdity). How can one prove this postulate:

```
  data ⊥ : Set where

  postulate exp : ∀ {n} {x : Set n} → ⊥ → x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can prove the principle of explosion as follows

```
  data ⊥ : Set where

  exp : ∀ {n} {x : Set n} → ⊥ → x
  exp ()
```

If one does not know how to prove this, one may start with a hole:

```
  data ⊥ : Set where

  exp : ∀ {n} {x : Set n} → ⊥ → x
  exp absurd = {! !}
```

Then, in emacs `agda2-mode` one can press `C-c C-l` to typecheck, so that hole will be replaced and emacs will show the target. In this case target is of type `.x`. Then one can click on that hole and press `C-c C-c` and type `absurd` to split this function by variable `absurd`. Emacs will produce the final result as given above.